# Issues when processing json data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib

Currently, when the input is a company, such as LinkedIn, the code is working perfectly and gives back the proper message. Email input is not working at all. Any suggestions? The current code is as follows:

```
import urllib
import json

userInput = input('Do you want to find an email (E) or company (C)? ')
userInput = userInput.upper()

def getResponse(url):
    cleanUrl = urllib.parse.quote_plus(url, safe=':/?&=')
    try:
        myRequest = urllib.request.Request(cleanUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})
        myResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(myRequest).read().decode('utf-8')
        myJSON = json.loads(myResponse)
        return myJSON
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        print('We failed with error code - ', err.code, '(', err.reason, ')')
        return
    except:
        print("Something else went terribly wrong!")

def takeInput():
    url = 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/'
    if userInput == 'E':
        email = input('What email do you want me to search for? ')
        fixedurl = url + 'breachedaccount/' + email
    elif userInput == 'C':
        company = input('What company do you want me to search for? ')
        fixedurl = url + 'breach/' + company 
    else:
        print('Invalid entry. Please type E or C.')

    myJSON = getResponse(fixedurl)
    for data in myJSON:
        name = myJSON.get("Name")
        date = myJSON.get("BreachDate")
        count = myJSON.get("PwnCount")
        itemsLost = myJSON.get("DataClasses")
        print("The", name,"breach occurred on", date,"and", count,"accounts were compromised. Iteams lost include:")
        print(itemsLost)
        break

takeInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a break;
for example :

```
while True:
     try:
         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
         break
     except ValueError:
         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

You could btw check this doc if you want to do it another way. Depends on your goals :

http://ozgur.github.io/python-linkedin/

Comment: Thank you! Adding the break helped. I still cannot get the email side of things to run. I keep getting a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Comment: You should btw use     "" fixedurl = url + 'breachedaccount/' + email ""